# Visual Studio new files have sub application relative urls

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I have a typical solution with multiple projects.

In IIS I have configured a new website with which to access my development area. Underneath this I have another sub application, pointing back to the same place. (This allows me to have mysite.com and mysite.com/au/)

This all works fine.

The problem I have now, when I create a new file (say an aspx page) and specify a master page (probably other scenarios as well) the relative link that is created is `~/au/masterpage.master`, not `~/masterpage.master` as one would expect.

As well as not loading in the CPH's of the master page (hugely annoying) this also breaks my page. So my question: Has anyone had this happen to them and how did they solve it?

**EDIT**

I found that if I removed the sub application and restarted VS, next time I created a file it worked as expected (without the `/au/`). However, it would be nice if I could leave the sub application in place.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  I hope its not actually "does this happen to anyone else" because that would be a waste of your time.

Comment: Modified my OP to specify the question.